# Main and Renderer handling promises, but Preload can be non-promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, electron

Considering the `renderer` and `main` are handling promises, will the code below force the process to become synchronous if `openFile()` is not also set to `async` `await`?

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI',
  {
    openFile: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile'),
    ...
```

If the code below is absolutely unnecessary, can somebody explain why `async` `await` can be omitted like in the code above?

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI',
  {
    openFile: async () => await ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile'),
    ...
```

FWIW:

```
// renderer.js

el.addEventListener('click', async ()=>{
  const filePath = await window.myAPI.openFile()
  el.textContent = filePath
})


// main.js

ipcMain.handle('dialog:openFile', async ()=>{
  const { canceled, filePaths } = await dialog.showOpenDialog()
  if (!canceled) return filePaths[0]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *[docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)*:

> ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args): 
> Returns Promise - Resolves with the response from the main process.

which suggests that the code without `async-await` will work correctly since ***`ipcRenderer.invoke` itself returns a Promise***. When you omit `async-await`, you're essentially returning the Promise returned by `ipcRenderer.invoke` directly. This means the ***`async-await` in your event listener will still handle the returned Promise correctly***, as it is expecting a Promise.

In summary, the use of `async-await` is not necessary and not using it will make your code concise and perform the same way as with it in this case because the function is returning a Promise directly, and the calling code (event listener) is already handling it with `async-await`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be omitted because either way you are returning a `Promise`. In the second example, you are creating an async function that waits for `ipcRenderer.invoke()`'s promise to resolve, then resolves itself.

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI',
  {
    openFile: async () => await ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile'), // () => Promise<...>
    ...
```

The `async`  keyword causes the function to return a `Promise`, rather than a value, so as `ipcRenderer.invoke` is async, and therefore already returns a `Promise`, there is no need to use the above syntax, which essentially wraps the ipcRenderer promise by itself.

This is what makes the first example functionally equivalent to the second. Both functions supply a `Promise`, and can both be `await`ed.

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI',
  {
    openFile: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFile'), // () => Promise<...>
    ...
```